How to get authorization header in Vue project?
I have a project written on Vue and uses Vue Router. I want to get Authorization header. As I can understand, Vue Router manages requests and route components. There is a method beforeEach in router object, which provide you an able to manage routing by yourself. That would be great if I can get http request when I make request to my site. Then I would be to get Authorization header from request and store it, for example, by provide method. But there is no any http request data, only routing data.
My Vue project hosts by nginx server which provide basic authorization by auth_basic parameter in nginx.conf file. Maybe I have another solution to pass Authorization header to Vue project?

vue router is just client-side javascript that figures out what components to replace in the DOM based on the URL.  it's part of what makes an SPA a "Single Page" Application. You have one index.html file that gets served, requiring a request to the web server. The loading of other "pages" is basically an illusion because it's all just that one index.html but with different components. What do you need an auth header for?  Do you have a separate API or other backend server?  I'm not sure what use an auth header would have for just a frontend by itself. The backend normally handles auth.

@yoduh, yes, I have a separate API in other backend server. As I can understand you I should to manage auth in my API and make some request to API from frontend to get username
